# Wordpress hosted behind a load balancer that provides SSL

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, wordpress, centos7

Clean Wordpress website located behind loadpalancer proxy that provides wildcard SSL for wp.mydomain.com but I'm not involved into its configuration. WP server based on CentOS 7.1 with Apache installed. I created simple Virtual Alias for the domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName wp.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/wp.mysite.com/public_html"
                <Directory "/var/www/wp.mysite.com/public_html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
           </Directory>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm
        <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
                ServerEnvironment apache apache
        </IfModule>
        ErrorLog /var/www/wp.mysite.com/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/wp.mysite.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything is fine with HTTP version of the site, but not with its HTTPS version. I'm getting **Mixed Content** issue while loading the site. Also I can't use WP admin, it's getting me into **Redirect loop** problem. I already added the next part of code to wp-config.php:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

define('WP_HOME','https://wp.mysite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://wp.mysite.com');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mixed content means that while you are connected over https some of the page elements such as images or linked CSS files and fonts are fetched using http - use the right click 'inspect element' on images and also look in the CSS files, for the redirect loop you can disable USE_SSL = true in wp_config file to FALSE. hope that helps.

Comment: In Chrome with Developer JavaScript Console open the page and it will tell you in red which assets are loaded insecurely. If you swap Apache for Nginx, you can substring replace these at the vhost level so you don't have to manually fix them all. There are also WP plugins which can help turn all http:// links into schemaless // links so you can easily get rid of this issue. The redirect loop can be investifated with tools like http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Comment: How can I change that on Apache level if there is no SSL certificates installed on the server where WP is allocated? Yes, I can use Chrome's debugger, but I see a lot of links css, js etc. I thought it should be easy to swap WP to use SSL

Comment: you need to get into the word press webroot and look at the files - https for admin access needs to be disabled and all http links for CSS need to be converted to https - you can't do anything in Apache about the mixed content and a mod rewrite for the admin section wouldn't get you out of the loop as the load balancer is already rewriting http requests to https. all of the answers point to the wordpress files.

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly how do I need to change everything to https als avoid redirect loops on admin panel?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL

Comment: you need to open the CSS files and scan for the scring http, most fonts and linked css file offer https resources, simply change them to https, if there  are any images in your wordpress that are not in your local /images folder (i.e hotlinked) - then these links need to be updated to https.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the load of static content behind some load balancer thaht have TLS termination you only need to add the next lines to `wp-config.php` file:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

You can see is very similar that you tried but the behavior is the opposite. If `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` value is different to `https` activate manually HTTPS on Wordpress even if the auto detection tell us the traffic is over http.

Answer (score 0):

Could be late but maybe helps someone, I found my self with the same problem, a Wordpress site ( without SSL ) behind a GCP LB ( with SSL), after some test I ended adding the following lines at the top of `index.php`:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false){
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
   $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME']='https';
   $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']=443;
}
```

It works just fine for me.